# Not found activity to handle intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-activity

I am writing a program where the main activity in my app should be invoked when a particular SMS arrives on the phone. I have already registered a `BroadcastReceiver` and the intent to invoke the activity is in the `onReceive()` method. The problem is, everytime I send this particular SMS, I get a Force close. Reading the logcat, I see the following NullPoint Exception:

```
10- 20 02:07:16.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    start receiver edu.example.prankssms3.SMSReceiverActivity3: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=edu.example.prankssms3.action.STARTMUSIC flg=0x10000000 }
```

But as far as am concerned everything is done right. Would anyone please tell me where the problem is? Thank you in advance.

**Here is the manifestfile:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity3"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity3" >
        <intent-filter>                
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="edu.example.prankssms3.action.STARTMUSIC" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="SMSReceiverActivity3">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**here is the broadcastreceiver**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // get the message passed in
        Bundle bdl = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if(bdl != null){
            // retrieve the sms message received
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bdl.get("pdus");         
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            }
            if(str.equals("FIRE_THE_MISSILES")){
                // The pranking comes here
                // start the activity to play the music and send sms    message
                Intent launchActivity = new Intent();
                launchActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                launchActivity.setAction("edu.example.prankssms3.action.STARTMUSIC");
                context.startActivity(launchActivity);
            }
        }
    }
```

**and here is the main class, which is also the class to be invoked by the intent:**

```
public class MainActivity3 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main3, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your `<intent-filter>` like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="edu.example.prankssms3.action.STARTMUSIC" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lanching an activity from a broadcast receiver is an not usual operation. Trying adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the Intent you use for startActivity().

Calling `startActivity()` from outside of an Activity context requires the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag. Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: My Intent already has the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. And apparently it's not helping

Comment: I added the following line in the intent-filter, just as Nikolai Samteladze said and it worked.                                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />